# Searchably record meeting attendees

Tags: org-mode

To aid minuting staff meetings in a small organisation, I considered creating a property called `:Attendees:` and [defining the allowed values](http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html) for that property, e.g.:

```
* Meetings
       :PROPERTIES:
       :Attendees_ALL: Amy Bob Joe Max Sam Zoe
       :END:
```

and then using them like this:

```
** Meeting 2017-05-17
       :PROPERTIES:
       :Attendees: Amy Joe Zoe
       :END:
```

However, I then [spotted that](http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-syntax.html) "a property can only have one entry per Drawer." So, Org-mode properties might not be a suitable tool for this after all.

I could use a simple list, I suppose, but **I want to easily be able to create [sparse trees matching](http://orgmode.org/manual/Property-searches.html) who was at a meeting.**

Using tags is also an option, but would be quite intrusive: potentially quite a long list of tags for each meeting. And not easily extendable to "Apologies", i.e. people who could not attend.

What might be a better solution?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it seems to me that if only one entry is allowed (and I'm taking your word for it), then one entry might be a list:  `'(Amy Bob Joe Max Sam Zoe)`?  I have no idea if we need double-quotes around each name, but I suspect it will be sufficient to use things like `(format "%s")` to convert when extracting to avoid things like a void variable, etc. ...  It may be fairly easy to treat everything in the property drawer as  one entry, but I haven't looked at the applicable code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exactly what you are trying to do like this.

Use regular expressions like this in your match expressions: Attendees={Joe\|Bob} to see meetings attended by Joe or Bob, or Attendees={Joe}-Attendees={Max} to see meetings attended by Joe and not Max.

Assuming you put an id like this in your heading with all the attendees (so you can retrieve them all later):

```
* Meetings
       :PROPERTIES:
       :CUSTOM_ID: main
       :Attendees_ALL: Amy Bob Joe Max Sam Zoe
       :END:
```

You can use a function like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(require 'dash)
(defun absent ()
  "Determine who was absent from the meeting."
  (interactive)
  (message "%s"
       (-difference
        (save-excursion
          (org-open-link-from-string "[[#main]]")
          (org-entry-get-multivalued-property nil "Attendees_ALL"))
        (org-entry-get-multivalued-property nil "Attendees"))))
#+END_SRC
```

to find who is absent.

Comment: Thanks :) Unfortunately, in Spacemacs, `M-x org-sparse-tree RET r Attendees={Joe\|Bob} RET` yields `0 match(es) for regexp Attendees={Joe\|Bob}`, even if the file contains entries with property drawers containing, e.g. `Attendees: Amy Joe Bob`. Was org-sparse-tree the command you had in mind for use with the match expressions you described?

Comment: You want =M-x org-sparse-tree RET m Attendees={Joe\|Bob} RET=. The key is to do a "match" on the tags/properties. I think r probably does a regex match on the headings.